# Combined Flair: determine which site new badges are from

Tags: support, badges, combined-flair

I noticed on my combined flair that I had been awarded another silver badge. How can I determine on which site this badge was awarded without logging into all sites and looking for the inbox notification?

Comment: The inbox notification should appear on any site, so long as the accounts are linked together.

Comment: This is not my experience for new badges.

Comment: @SabreWolfy: Bronze badge notifications are supressed if you are a 'experienced' user (account on more than one site, association bonus, or similar requirements, can't quite recall). All other badges are notified. The notification box is *global*, shown on all sites regardless.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Only *some* bronze badges. But he mentioned a silver badge in the post, and I'm not aware of any veteran silver badges.

Comment: @SabreWolfy: This is what it should look like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yFOah.jpg - Your inbox is the same across the entire network. You don't get notifications *only* for the site you're currently on.

Comment: @animuson: Yup, just providing extra information to account for the OP's experience that new badges are not being notified.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to monitor it more carefully in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to log into all of the sites. Only one of them. The [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/172936) has a notifications tab that will show you exactly what new badges you have and on what site they were awarded -

[image]

As you can see from the screen shot, my two most recent badges were awarded right here on meta. You can see from the sites logo and also by clicking on the notification, you'll be sent to the relevant site.

Comment: Another place: http://stackexchange.com/users/282850/sabrewolfy?tab=activity (choose "badges" filter, for some reason it's not added to the URL)